# script to rename filenames containing backslash

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

I am trying to write a shell script to rename the result of 7-zipped folders. The resulting filenames contains backslash \ in the filename.
I wrote a simple :

```
#! /bin/sh

for n in * do
  OldName=$n
  NewName=`echo "$n" | tr -s '\' "#" | tr -s " " "_"`
  echo $NewName
  mv "$OldName" "$NewName"
done
```

The problem I have is that \01 is interpreted by echo, and my files are :
FLD\01.02.2015 thefile.pdf

Thus, echo "FLD\01.02.2015 thefile.pdf" returns FLD?.2015.

I have tried various replacement solutions, s/\/#/g, sed, tr. 
I tried to use printf instead
I have search all over the net without finding a valid solution.

Nothing works. I need a solution that would work on Unix and Mac OS X.

the only "working" solution would be to

```
ls > liste.txt
sed -e 's/\\/,/g' liste.txt
```

and then parse liste.txt, escape the backslash, generate a rename.sh and execute it. But this seems really dirty to me.

Does anyone has a suggestion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `echo` to rename the filename you can do this (in Bash):

```
NewName="${OldName//\\/}"
```

Example:

```
OldName="FLD\01.02.2015 thefile.pdf"
NewName="${OldName//\\/}"
echo "$NewName"
```

It will print out:

```
FLD01.02.2015 thefile.pdf
```

Note: You will need to change the shebang to `#!/bin/bash` to use bash parameter expansion.

Comment: Excellent! I didn't know about parameters expansion 

${mystring//search/replace}

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If you care about literal data, don't use `echo`. Its results are not well defined.

You can instead use `printf`, also POSIX, which doesn't mangle data.

```
NewName=`printf "%s" "$n" | tr -s '\' "#" | tr -s " " "_"`
```